# Count how many times a string repeats itself SCALA

Tags: string, scala, count, repeat

Hi I´m trying to get the number of times an artist name repeats in some years for this I have this

```
var artists=Array.ofDim[String](994,2)//artist,year
var artists2=Array.ofDim[String](250)//artist name
var artists3 = Array.ofDim[Int](250)//number of times
```

And the user has to enter ano1 and ano2 that are the years margin we want

```
val loop = new Breaks;
  for(i <- 0 to 993){//copiamos
      loop.breakable{
        for(j<- 0 to 249){
            if(artists2(j).contentEquals("NULL") && artists(i)(1).toInt>=ano1 && artists(i)(1).toInt<=ano2){
              artists2(j)=artists(i)(0)
              artists3(j)= 1
              loop.break;
            }else if(artists(i)(0).contentEquals(artists2(j)) && artists(i)(1).toInt>=ano1 && artists(i)(1).toInt<=ano2){
              artists3(j)= artists3(j)+1
              loop.break;

            }

        }
       }
  }

 println(artists2.mkString("\n")) 
 println(artists3.mkString(","))
```

For some reason my if doesnt work or j add itself 1 after entering in the if because every time is creating a new element in artists2 instead of adding it to artists3

The output I get is artists3 filled with 1 because for some reason it never checks the other part of the if

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm sorry if this sounds a bit harsh, but there are so many things wrong with your code it's hard to know where to begin.

The main problems are 1) your code isn't very scala-like, and 2) you're using data structures and variable names designed to make things as difficult as possible to understand.

Here's a brief attempt to redesign things.  It may not meet all your requirements but perhaps it will start you in a better direction.

```
val mockdata = List( ("Tom", 2001)
                   , ("Sue", 2002)
                   , ("Joe", 2002)
                   , ("Sue", 2005)
                   , ("Sue", 2004)
                   , ("Jil", 2001)
                   , ("Tom", 2005)
                   , ("Sue", 2002)
                   , ("Jil", 2012)
                   )

def countArtists( dataSet: List[(String,Int)]
                , anoStart: Int , anoEnd: Int): Map[String,Int] = {
  val artists = for {
    (artist, year) <- dataSet
    if year >= anoStart && year <= anoEnd
  } yield artist
  artists.distinct.map(name => name -> artists.count(_ == name)).toMap
}

val count2002to2011 = countArtists(mockdata, 2002, 2011)
```

At this point you can use the result to get interesting information.

```
scala> count2002to2011.keys // all artists within the time period
res0: Iterable[String] = Set(Sue, Joe, Tom)

scala> count2002to2011.values.sum // total count within the time period
res1: Int = 6

scala> count2002to2011("Sue") // count for just this artist
res2: Int = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

your implementation seems a little bit confused, if i understood what you needed, i would like if i may, share how i would have implemented your research, in a more functionnal/scala and clear way.

```
case class Artist(name: String, year: Int)
case class ArtistNames(name: String)
case class ArtistResult(name: String, nbOccurence: Int)


val anno1 = 1950
val anno2 = 1960

def checkArtist(artists: Seq[Artist], artistNames: Seq[ArtistNames]): Seq[ArtistResult] = {
  artists.map{ artist =>
    def countOccurence(artist: Artist, artistNames: Seq[ArtistNames], occurence: Int): Int = {
      artistNames match {
        case Nil => occurence
        case head :: tail =>
          if (head.name == artist.name && artist.year >= anno1 && artist.year <= anno2) countOccurence(artist, tail, occurence + 1)
          else countOccurence(artist, tail, occurence)
      }
    }
    val occurrence = countOccurence(artist, artistNames, 0)
    ArtistResult(artist.name, occurrence)
  }
}

val artistResultList: Seq[ArtistResult] = checkArtist(/* insert your data here */)
```

i hope i answered a little bit your question.

Comment: I discovered my error it seems like compareTo equals or even use == doesnt work so the second if never triggers can you help me with my implementation yours seems very complicated

Comment: why do you try to do anything if artist2(j) == null ? why don't you just try your valid data and increment your value only at this time ? i mean why don't you just do the "else" part of your condition ?